# $('body').on("change") is not wroking after upgrading jquery from 1.8.2 to 1.11.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, razor

I have the following script inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on("submit", "form", function () {

        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    $('body').on("change", "form", function () {
        $(this).find('.btn-primary').prop("disabled",false);


    });
});
```

the purpose of the script is as follow:-

- to disable the button on submitting the form.
- to enable the button again when the form is changed.

But after upgrading the jQuery from 1.8.2 o 1.11.2 it is partially working on partial view. for example when i submit a form that is rendered insdie a partial view, button will be disabled, but if i start typing on the form , for example after a client side validation error , the button will never be enabled again?

can anyone adivce on this please ?

Thanks.

Comment: For submit it should be `.prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: but it is disabling the button when submitting,, the problem is with enabling it again , when the form is changed...

Comment: Right, but I suspect there might be a check of some kind to do nothing if the current value is unexpected. I could be completely wrong, but won't hurt to try anyway

Comment: It seems to work correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/1euk20zf/

Comment: i just realize that the problem is if the button is within a partial view , the button will be disabled ,, but will never be enabled again. as i said this script ws working 100% on jQuery 1.8.2 but after the upgrade to 1.11.2 seems the  $('body').on("change", "form", function () will not have any effect on partial views ?

Comment: @johnG the view shouldn't matter... you're using event delegation to bind the event to the form regardless of when a view is rendered. Maybe there's a JS error or something?

Comment: i updated my question accordingly ,,

Comment: @Chad but the disabled, enable senario is working well on normal views,, while it will not work on partial views..

Comment: @johnG okay, so what happens if you bind your events to the document instead of the body?